# Is the base damage of an elite monster based on the damage of the non-elite version?

Tags: diablo-iii

Has anyone done any analysis on the relationship between elite monsters and their base types?

For instance, is the damage of an elite skeleton group some percentage higher than the damage of non-elite skeletons, and is it consistent?

Do these values differ between Elite, Champion, and Unique monster spawns? What about across difficulties?

What about HP of elite monster? Does this also have a similar relationship?

Ultimately I want to know whether Elites/Rares/Champions/Unique monsters stats are generated based off of the original monster data or if they have their own custom values for each elite type/monster type combination.

Lastly, I'll try to investigate this issue on my own over the next few weeks and update my progress here. If anyone has any tips on how to approach this issue please let me know in answers or comments.

Thanks!

Comment: in my experience they are based on the original monsters data, for example elite soul lashers hit a lot harder than goblin elite minions. I don't have any stats to actually back this up though.

Comment: I am hoping this is the case. My goal is to pin down, if any, a relationship between the base monster types and the elite monsters. But as fbueckert stated in his answer below, he does not expect to see that elites actually do more damage, on a per hit basis, than their non-elite counter parts.

Answer (score 2):

As these pages of a guide I found on diablofans suggest there is no added damage to champions or elites.

- http://media.diablofans.com/images/news/2012/may/guide/IMG_0101.jpg
- http://media.diablofans.com/images/news/2012/may/guide/IMG_0102.jpg
- http://media.diablofans.com/images/news/2012/may/guide/IMG_0103.jpg
- http://media.diablofans.com/images/news/2012/may/guide/IMG_0104.jpg

It seems there is a guaranteed min damage per hit and some bonus effects are added. The main dps for champions and elites comes from their affixes.

Comment: Good find!  That corroborates my observations.

Answer (score 1):

From lots (and lots, and lots) of experience in Acts 1 and 2 Inferno, I do not believe Elites and Champions gain any extra stats beyond health from being an Elite or Champion.  There are abilities that increase various attributes (Fast, Extra Health, etc.), but Elites and Champions don't hit harder or move faster just because they're above average.

When a monster is attacking you (ie. using their default attacks, not something conferred by an ability), I have not noticed *any* of them hitting harder or moving faster than their normal counterparts.

The difficulty from these monsters comes from the special abilities and AI modifications conferred by being above average.  As far as I have been able to determine, abilities that directly cause damage (Arcane Enchanted, Fire Chains, Molten, etc.) don't base their damage off the monster type; it comes from their level.  ie.  All Molten fire patches in Act 1 Inferno will do the same amount of damage, regardless of which monster is generating them.  This is because all monsters in Act 1 Inferno are level 61.  Molten monsters will also often try to walk around you, to make sure you're standing in their fire.

Unique monsters are slightly different; they have special names and the same abilities and monster model, regardless of when you meet them.  These monsters have their own set parameters that they will spawn with.

When a monster is initially spawned, you *can* notice that some randomization is going on, just by looking at their health values.  This same randomization would apply to above average monsters (including Uniques), after which their special abilities would be calculated and finalized.

I have no official source or methodical testing to base this off of; it all comes from my observations when fighting groups of monsters.

Comment: Thank you for your analysis. I'll be on the look out to see if this is true as well. Testing this hypothesis will be much easier to confirm or deny than testing to see what ratios do exist, as far as damage is concerned. If your observations are indeed true, this will make the program I am working on MUCH easier.

Comment: I've definitely seen Elites/Champions hit harder than normal. Dark Berserkers and the charging elephantrhinobulls from Act I definitely do more damage.

Comment: I kind of disagree with your statement that the elites/champs do not hit harder. I am pretty certain they in fact do. I can go toe to toe with most mobs without a problem, with elite packs without reflect or any kind of direct offensive ability.

Comment: I've read elsewhere(some comment here) that elites are a bit faster than their mundane counterparts - which I can confirm as true for some of the Act 1 mobs (the elite slow guys waddle noticeably faster even without 'Fast' ability)

Comment: I'm not sure how it's calculated, but at least in inferno, at least some elites hit quite a bit harder.

Comment: Hmm.  I'll poke around and see what I can find out.